# Manually load more items with Waypoints Infinite Scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

I am using Waypoints Infinite Scroll and I want to make a “Load more Items” or “Load more Posts” button.

I tried using 'destroy' like this but it doesn’t seem to work.

```
    $('.load-more-button').click(function(){

        var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
            element: $('.infinite-container')[0],
            onAfterPageLoad: function() {
                $('.infinite-container').waypoint('destroy')
            }
        })

    });
```

Really stuck here, thanks for any help!

Comment: by calling `var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite()` you are instantiating it. What exactly you want to do? sorry, but I am not getting your question.

Comment: I just want to have a load more button, instead having the items loaded automatically. Like this:[link] (http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/bEdfX/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked 4 years ago, but I guess we have the same question. I was trying to make the button trigger the same event that the scroll does. I could do it with this code:

```
// Initializing Waypoint Infinite
var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
    element: $('.infinite-container')[0]
});

// Listen for the click on the button, and then trigger the event
$('.infinite-more-link').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    infinite.waypoint.trigger();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
$('.load-more-button').click(function(){
    $(".infinite-more-link").click(); //Infinite Scroll create a <a> element with "infinite-more-link" class by default for More link.
});
```

Comment: I’m sorry I think I forgot to mention that I want to click, load some items and stop. And click again for more items…

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting that you want to take away half of what Infinite does, and you may as well just write the AJAX load + append yourself on click without using Waypoints at all. But if you insist:

```
$('.infinite-container').waypoint('destroy')
```

That is old Waypoints 2.x style code. Destroy and other methods aren't part of the jQuery plugin anymore. You need to use the Waypoint instance you created:

```
infinite.destroy()
```